# How do I prevent App Store showing badge on its icon on OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, dock

On both Dock and Launchpad.

I opened App Store by mistake, and now I cannot remove the badge which is designed for reminding me updates, except I install all the updates or delete all the apps which have updates.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Notifications (which include icon badges) are not configurable for the Mac App Store app.

Comment: However, this feature should rely on some APIs, meaning that would be possible if I destroy the API dependency tree or modify some configuration profile (plist or Core Data or what else)... Would you make some research on that, please? I'll appreciate...